# Make PHP include only appear on certain URLs?

Tags: php

I'm not the best at coding PHP, HTML and CSS are more where my expertise lie.

I would like to have a PHP file included into the homepage of my site, but only the homepage and not on any other page within the site, as the element in question is based in a header.php file and would appear on every other page otherwise. Is this possible to do and if so how could it be done?

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: check your current `URL` and use `if-else` condition to import the file.

Comment: @RonakPatel Would you be able to give me a coded example of this? As I mentioned i'm not the best when it comes to coding PHP! Thankyou.

Comment: can you post different `URL` that you'r getting on different pages?

Comment: @RonakPatel So the file slider.php would be included in a header.php file, which slider.php is to be only shown on index.php and hidden from any other url.

Comment: I think your code in index.php should be like this :

`<?php
include('file.php') ;
include('header.php');
?>`
So put the file which you like to include out of header and just in index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [server superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), and request URI to check for the home page.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php')
        include('somefile.php');
?>
```

EDIT:

Got ninja'd, keep in mind that your home page could be requested a couple ways if you are using index.php. Also: Fairly sure that there is always an opening / on URIs, as it is just the verbatim query string for the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post any code. So, I assume one of the condition here.
You can try something like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="index.php" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==""){
    // include your file..
    include('somefile.php');
}
?>
```

**P.S.:** I assume that `index.php` is your default home page.
You should search more on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the variables, but this should do the trick.

```
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "yourHomePage.php") {
    include_once("yourinclude.php");
}
```

You may need to echo the basename of the page to get it exactly right.  I cannot remember if it will have a / on the front.

```
echo(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```